# How to access 'x-headers' header in nginx openresty?

Tags: nginx, lua, xmlhttprequest, openresty

I sent a request with x-user-agent header.
However, I can't access x-user-agent in ngx.req.get_headres().
It doesn't contains 'x-user-agent' key:

```
 host, x-forwarded-host, accept, x-forwarded-server, x-forwarded-proto, x-forwarded-for, user-agent, accept-encoding, x-real-ip, x-forwarded-port, x-forwarded-prefix
```

How to list x-headers as well?

Comment: What is the whole request flow? Direct to nginx or something in between?

Answer (score 5):

I think you want `User-Agent` not `x-user-agent`

```
ngx.req.get_headers()['User-Agent']
```

This can be an array in most case a string, see https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqget_headers